# Remover dados duplicados de um array de objetos

Tags: javascript, react

gostaria de saber como faço para **remover dados duplicados de um array de objetos**. Tentei da forma abaixo, se tiver outra forma melhor por favor me fale :

Primeiramente criei dois arrays e depois mesclei os dois

```
let firstArray = [
      { name: "javascript", id: 1 },
      { name: "golang", id: 2 },
      { name: "python", id: 3 },
    ];

    let secondArray = [
      { name: "javascript", id: 1 },
      { name: "golang", id: 2 },
      { name: "python", id: 3 },
      { name: "ruby", id: 4 },
      { name: "elixir", id: 5 },
      { name: "rust", id: 6 },
    ];

const merge = [...firstArray,...secondArray];
```

Usei o método SET para remover as duplicatas :

```
 const unique = [...new Set(merge.map((language)=> language.id  ))]
    
 console.log(unique) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

Dessa forma ele removeu as duplicatas, mas o output dele me traz somente os ids e eu gostaria que trouxesse também o name.

Comment: É porque voce está retornando os valores de cada `language.id` no array map

Comment: Como consigo retornar os dados com nome e id? Tentei passar language ao inves de language.id no map, mas o output dele retornar todos os items(inclusive duplicados).